# What can I learn at open-house events for PhD programs that would be difficult to learn through other channels prior to accepting an offer?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I have received a few offers for PhD programs in the US that I am interested in, and several of these have open-house events coming up in the next few weeks.  I have been in contact with potential advisors at several of these programs, but have had very limited or no contact with current graduate students there.  My current information on these programs comes from offer letters, interactions with professors (both my undergraduate advisor, and professors at institutions hosting these open-houses), and departmental websites.

My primary goals with these events are:

1. Meet with potential advisors, and determine who I could work well with, and
2. Talk to current PhD students; see if I can learn anything about departmental politics, the funding situation, and anything else that the department doesn't advertise to prospective students.

Which questions should I be sure to ask, and to whom?  What opportunities do I have at open-houses that I will never have again before I need to accept an offer?

If it matters, the programs I am considering are in physics, geophysics and Earth sciences departments, depending on which department the space sciences faculty happen to be in.

Comment: We've already covered "What questions should I be sure to ask" very, very thoroughly: see [What are some good questions to ask current graduate students when visiting schools?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/353/what-are-some-good-questions-to-ask-current-graduate-students-when-visiting-scho), [What are the 'right questions' to ask professors at a visit day for prospective graduate students?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17192/what-are-the-right-questions-to-ask-professors-at-a-visit-day-for-prospective),

Comment: (continued)  [What questions should one ask to the former/current students of a professor before deciding whether to do PhD under him/her?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8507/what-questions-should-one-ask-to-the-former-current-students-of-a-professor-befo)... I'm having trouble seeing a reason to keep this open. Can you [edit] this post to emphasize how it is different from those other questions?

Comment: @ff524 Clearly I wasn't searching for the right questions; it looks like the three questions you posted cover my issue pretty thoroughly.  I'm new here; should I delete this question, or does someone with higher reputation "close" it?

Comment: If those do indeed cover your question, I'll close this one as a duplicate of one of those. That's better than deleting it, because that way it still shows in search results and will help direct other people towards the answer :)

Comment: Some more questions to ask: [What should I ask my potential Ph.D advisor in advance, before actually signing a contract?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/23130/what-should-i-ask-my-potential-ph-d-advisor-in-advance-before-actually-signing)