# Contact previous postdocs of a potential postdoc supervisor to receive feedbacks

Tags: etiquette, postdocs

I have been offered a postdoc position in a very good university.

However, I had a quite negative impression from the PI, who looked a bit bossy. Also, I had the sensation that he is looking more for a manger of his phd students (who btw have a better CV than me) rather than for a researcher.

Given these doubts, I would like to contact a previous postdoc of this professor, to have a feedback on his experience.

Is this a bad idea? Or is it something common?

Comment: Similar to https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/104777/etiquette-for-reaching-out-to-previous-students-of-advisor